# Having trouble with ThemeProvider applying the theme from my Redux Store in React.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, material-ui

GitHub: https://github.com/AplUSAndmINUS/terence-waters-reactmui

I'm trying to apply a MUI theme I've created in a Redux store to supply a light or dark mode based on a user toggle. The default is lightMode, which you can see in the toggle-theme.ts reducer. I know it works because the theme object is returned successfully and toggles with a button in the page-shell.tsx file.

I've also properly wrapped my project in a ThemeProvider from @mui/material/styles as per the documentation on Material 5.0 in my index.tsx file. I also had to split the root from the project in my index.tsx because you have to use a "useSelector" within a component, not the render function itself. ([Change Material UI theme from Redux-toolkit Global Store Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68950724/change-material-ui-theme-from-redux-toolkit-global-store-dynamically))

I get a bunch of undefined errors with the typography variants, pxToRem properties, and so on from within the "PageShell" page/component, "* Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'h1') in Typography component". It means the theme isn't being loaded, though the variable is defined as an object properly by the browser.

Any ideas? Here's my code to help--sorry for the brevity, and thanks in advance!

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Provider, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

/* Custom variables */
import { store } from './store/store';

/* Pages import */

const Root = () => {
  const theme = useSelector((state: any) => state.theme);
  console.log(theme);
  
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<PageShell />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path="/content" element={<ContentShell />}>
              <Route path="blog" element={<Blog />} />
              <Route path="events" element={<Events />} />
              <Route path="github" element={<GitHub />} />
              <Route path="music" element={<Music />} />
              <Route path="portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
              <Route path="writing" element={<Writing />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
};

const container: any = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Root />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

actions.ts

```
export const TOGGLE_THEME = 'TOGGLE_THEME';

export function toggleTheme() {
  return { type: TOGGLE_THEME };
}
```

toggle-theme.ts (reducer)

```
import { green, red, yellow } from '@mui/material/colors';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

import { TOGGLE_THEME } from '../actions/actions';

// Custom Theme creation
export const lightTheme = createTheme({
  // LONG object
});

export const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#a4c3e6',
      contrastText: '#fff'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#333',
      contrastText: '#dedede'
    },
    // LONG object #2
});

const initialState = {
  theme: lightTheme
};

export function themeReducer(state = initialState, action: any) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_THEME:
      return {
        ...state,
        theme: state.theme === lightTheme ? darkTheme : lightTheme
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

page-shell.tsx

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { IconButton, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { DarkMode, LightMode } from '@mui/icons-material';

import { toggleTheme } from '../../store/actions/actions';

export const PageShell = () => {
  const darkMode = useSelector((state: any) => state.theme.darkMode);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <>
      <IconButton 
        color="secondary" 
        disableRipple
        disableFocusRipple
        onClick={() => dispatch(toggleTheme())}>
        {darkMode ? <DarkMode /> : <LightMode />}
      </IconButton>
      <Typography variant="h1">PageShell page</Typography>
    </>
  )
};

export default PageShell;
```

Comment: In case anyone wishes to see the Theme Objects, you can find them here: https://codepen.io/AplUSAndmINUS/pen/eYPMZyz

Comment: While it's technically "allowed", Redux doesn't like [nor always gracefully handles] complex objects stored in state and prefers simple/plain objects. It would probably be better/easier to just store the theme objects outside of Redux and toggle them based on a simple [string] key stored in state. FWIW: I tested the code from your repo, but modified it to toggle from a string in state, and it worked just fine.

Comment: So good call, and yes, this worked for me also once I changed it to useState and useEffect to apply it. I'm wondering though...

I really only need to destructure the "palette" object properties for light and dark mode and return this from Redux. That's possible using a "mode" action, I'd assume?

Comment: I wanted to go ahead and offer the solution to this issue.

It took me several weeks to troubleshoot, but Redux likes to pass things as a serialized version of JSON, which createTheme() adds its own flair to objects when getting passed down. 

I was able to fix the problem by telling Redux to send it as a createTheme() object, rather than just an object itself. I also had to apply createTheme() to the ThemeProvider prop itself because it wouldn't translate properly without it. 

In short: Apply createTheme() everywhere it's needed throughout the project so Redux knows the type. :)